# The "on $\left\{ \tau <\infty \right\}$" in the Strong Markov Property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

The strong Markov property is often formulated as $$P[\theta _{\tau}X\in  A\mid \mathscr
F_{\tau}]\overset{\text {a.s on }\left\{ \tau <\infty \right\}
}{=}P_{X_\tau}(X\in A)$$

- What *exactly* does "on $\left\{ \tau <\infty \right\}$" mean? Intuitively it seems we're conditioning on this event, but I'm unsure.
- <s>Is there a way to restate the strong Markov property as a conditional independence?</s>

***Edit:*** Since, as Did points out, the questions are unrelated, I'll ask the second one separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two unrelated questions, for the first one, the assertion that "$X=Y$ almost surely on $A$" means that the event $[X\ne Y]\cap A$ has probability zero.